# How to scroll to top when a button is clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a button on a page and I want that when it is clicked, the page scrolls to the 0 position.

HTML

```
<button id="button">Back to top </button>
```

jquery

```
$(document).scroll(function(){

        var scroll_pos = $(window).scrollTop()
    if(scroll_pos > 10){

        $('#button').click(function(){

        // what code to enter here??


        });

    }
    });
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try this code:

```
$("#button").on("click", function() {
    $("body").scrollTop(0);
});
```

Method `on` binds a `click` event to the button and `scrollTop` scrolls your `body` to 0 position.

Comment: There's no need to use jQuery for the scrolling in this case.  `window.scroll(0, 0)` will work just fine in all browsers.  See the MDN article on it - https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Window.scroll.

Comment: Well, guys. In fact there is not need to use JavaScript at all: HTML anchors can make the same thing :) @Ronny, you are welcome!

Answer (score 14):

you can use window function for `scrollTop` jquery

```
 $("#button").click( function() {
   $(window).scrollTop(0);
 });
```

When you click button, this page scroll to top of the position.

Answer (score 5):

***Try It***

```
$("#button").click(function() {
        $("html").scrollTop(0);
        });
```

**or**

```
$("#button").click(function() {
        $("html").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, "slow");
        });
```

Comment: "html" worked for me but using  "body" it didn't. Any idea why?