# Targeting parent frame when event happens in iframe

Tags: jquery, iframe

I'm using an iframe to show a form that spits out search results. I'm using an [iframe resizer](https://github.com/davidjbradshaw/iframe-resizer) to make the experience relatively seamless.

Trouble is, when the user submits the form the page doesn't go back up to the top of the browser window leaving the user in the middle of the results.

I'm using jQuery and tried [the scrollTop() function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10461152/how-to-scroll-to-top-when-a-button-is-clicked-in-jquery) but no dice.

Unfortunately the page is behind a password so I can't provide a link. Any ideas on how I should approach this? I see a few other posting about this, but none seemed to help. I've tried

```
$(".submit").on("click", function() {
   $("body").scrollTop(0);
});
```

and

```
$('iframe').contents().find('.submit').click(function() {
    alert('click');
});
```

Comment: Is the `iframe` content on the same domain as the parent? `parent.document` should get you there. If not, you need to use `window.postMessage`.

Comment: Please define *none*. What have you tried? Show some code.

Comment: Yes, the iframe is in the same domain. Updated the post to include code.